# notepad++: keep regex (multi occurence per line) and line structure, remove other characters

Tags: regex, notepad++, data-cleaning

I have a 130k line text file with patent information and I just want to keep the dates (regex `"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} "`) for subsequent work in Excel. For this purpose I need to keep the line structure intact (also blank lines). My main problem is that I can't seem to find a way to identify and keep multiple occurrences of date information in the same line while deleting all other information.

Original file structure:

```
US20110228428A1 | US |   | 7 | 2010-03-19 | SEAGATE TECHNOLOGY LLC
US20120026629A1 | US |   | 7 | 2010-07-28 | TDK CORP | US20120127612A1 | US |   | EXAMINER | 2010-11-24 |   | US20120147501A1 | US |   | 2 | 2010-12-09 | SAE MAGNETICS HK LTD,HEADWAY TECHNOLOGIES INC
```

Desired file structure:

```
2010-03-19 
2010-07-28 2010-11-24 2010-12-09
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for

```
.*?(?:([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})|$)
```

And replace with

```
" $1"
```

Don't put the quotes, just to show there is a space before the `$1`. This will also put a space before the first match in a row.

This regex will match as less as possible `.*?` before it finds either the Date or the end of the row (the `$`). If a date is found it is stored in `$1` because of the brackets around. So as replacement just put a space to separate the found dates and then the found date from `$1`.